# What $T$ and $P$ refers to in potentials $F$ and $G$?

Tags: thermodynamics, potential

The below are definitions for Helmholtz and Gibbs energies

$$F=U-TS$$
$$G=U+PV-TS$$

I am confused about whether $T$ and $P$ refer to the temperature and pressure of a system *or* reservoir. Some sources mention that $T$ and $P$ are the temperature and pressure of the reservoir, not system while others mention the opposite.

Answer (score 6):

It is always the temperature and pressure of the *system*.

Having said that, the Helmholtz energy is useful in analyzing a process under constant temperature and constant volume. To maintain constant temperature we need a bath and in this case $T$ is the same in the system and in the bath.

Similarly, the Gibbs energy is useful in analyzing process at constant $T$ and $P$. By the same argument, temperature *and* pressure in this case would be the same as in the surroundings.

Answer (score 2):

Concerning the state functions $F(T,V)$ and $G(T,P$) they are of course defined with the state variables. They are obtained by Legendre transformation from $U(S,V)$ and contain all the thermodynamic information about the system.

Concerning the thermodynamic potentials which must be minimized for a system in contact with a source of temperature $T_0$ or a source of temperature $T_0$ and pressure $P_0$, it is more delicate. I limit myself to the second case to be brief.

When we follow the reasoning in detail, the thermodynamic potential to be minimized is indeed $A=U+P_0V-T_0S$ and not $G=U+PV-TS$. This potential $A$ is not a state function. It is sometimes called "Gouy function" or in a more modern way "exergy". The difference is important because, in a transformation which is not reversible, the temperature $T$ or the pressure $P$ of the system may not even be defined during the transformation, even if the system is in contact with a source of temperature $T_0$ or pressure $P_0$.

In chemistry, for example, we are most often in contact with the atmosphere, a source of temperature and pressure, and we are looking for the extend of reaction $x$ that minimizes the thermodynamic potential (law of mass action). But it is not rare that the system heats up or even explodes in the worst case! We cannot therefore say that the temperature or pressure of the system is the same as that of the sources (the atmosphere).  We should therefore minimize $A=U+P_0V-T_0S$ and not $G(T,P,x)$.

But we get away with it because we know that at the end, once equilibrium is reached, the temperature will be $T_0$ and the pressure $P_0$. We can therefore minimize $G(T_0,P_0,x)$ by limiting ourselves to the states for which the temperature and pressure are those of the source even if this is not what happened in the real transformation.